# Get last day of specific(SEPTEMBER) month

Tags: java, date

How to get the fiscal year end date (2017-09-30) dynamically.
Based on the year I need to get the fiscal year end date dynamically.

For example:

If 2017 then output should be 2017-09-30
If 2018 then output should be 2018-09-30 and so on.

Code:

```
 Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.SEPTEMBER);
```

Output I am getting as "4"

Can I know how to get the end date dynamically.

Comment: The solution is a simple String concatenation. The only dynamic property is the year. The rest is always the same:
getEndOfSept(String year){
return year + "-09-30";
}

Comment: Aside from anything else, do you *have* to keep using the horrible Calendar API? If you can use Joda Time or java.time you'll end up with far fewer horrible hacks.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
private static String getDate(int month, int year) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // passing month-1 because 0-->jan, 1-->feb... 11-->dec
    calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return DATE_FORMAT.format(date);
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: I am not going to pass any input. It need to pick it dynamically

Comment: dynamically pass values and get result then.

Comment: if you want to find only of September you can hard code month=9 or you can iterate it for each month.

Comment: Based on year, I have to get the September month. Date and month remains constant

Comment: @Nidhi257 Except, whoops, the `Calendar` class has crazy numbering of months where `9` is *not* September. Use java.time classes instead, specifically [`Month.SEPTEMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#SEPTEMBER).

Answer (score 0):

## Fiscal year?

The term “fiscal year” is not defined here. Usually that is a company-specific definition, and may not be as simple as “end of September”.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

If you are asking for the same month and same day-of-month but adjusted by year, use the java.time classes. The troublesome `Calendar` class is now legacy, and should be avoided.

## `LocalDate` & `MonthDay`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class represents a month and day-of-month without any year and without any time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 30 );
MonthDay md = MonthDay.from( ld );
LocalDate ldInAnotherYear = md.atYear( ld.getYear() + 1 );
```

You could also simply add a year depending on the date in question and what your desired behavior is for handling the last days of a month since months have different lengths, and of course February has the issue of Leap Year.

```
LocalDate yearLater = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 30 ).plusYears( 1 );
```

## `YearMonth`

You might find the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class handy. You can ask it for the last day of the month.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth( 2017 , Month.SEPTEMBER );
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth();
```

I recommend using objects rather than mere integers. Consider passing around objects such as `YearMonth`, `MonthDay`, `LocalDate`, and [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) where appropriate rather than numbers.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).